# Wrong area in STArea() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial, wkt

I am trying to count the surface (`STArea ()`) of a geometry saved as a WKT, but I get the wrong value.

I mention that using geography did not help. I also noticed, that in Postgis area is counted properly when I set use_spheroid=false.

```
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((21.5601775022348 52.1813862660549,21.5601461469143 52.1813295549141,21.559853091877 52.1813993365177,21.5597665803865 52.1812613330339,21.5593037698201 52.1813692515792,21.5592677194965 52.1813021172669,21.5592607711581 52.1813034375092,21.5592188506351 52.1812334620465,21.5591248909245 52.1812561912586,21.5590395906618 52.1811137531269,21.5587491625113 52.1811808662478,21.5589985172752 52.1816470941761,21.5595646783963 52.1815219107667,21.5601775022348 52.1813862660549))', 4326);  
select @g;
select @g.STArea()
```

Comment: What is the "correct" area and in what unit of measure?  Is the square of the unit of measure for the polygon vertexes?  Why are you using a non-zero SRID with Geometry?

Comment: Correct area getting from PostGIS query `SELECT St_Area( ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((21.5601775022348 52.1813862660549,21.5601461469143 52.1813295549141,21.559853091877 52.1813993365177,21.5597665803865 52.1812613330339,21.5593037698201 52.1813692515792,21.5592677194965 52.1813021172669,21.5592607711581 52.1813034375092,21.5592188506351 52.1812334620465,21.5591248909245 52.1812561912586,21.5590395906618 52.1811137531269,21.5587491625113 52.1811808662478,21.5589985172752 52.1816470941761,21.5595646783963 52.1815219107667,21.5601775022348 52.1813862660549))', 4326), false);`
is 2286.22

Comment: square meters. I am new to SQL Server, so I use 4326 SRID like in PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

In geography, the left hand side is the interior as you traverse the polygon.  So you have specified the inverse of the polygon you want.  With geometry it doesn't matter, as the interior is always the the bounded area.

Try

```
DECLARE @g geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((21.5601775022348 52.1813862660549,21.5601461469143 52.1813295549141,21.559853091877 52.1813993365177,21.5597665803865 52.1812613330339,21.5593037698201 52.1813692515792,21.5592677194965 52.1813021172669,21.5592607711581 52.1813034375092,21.5592188506351 52.1812334620465,21.5591248909245 52.1812561912586,21.5590395906618 52.1811137531269,21.5587491625113 52.1811808662478,21.5589985172752 52.1816470941761,21.5595646783963 52.1815219107667,21.5601775022348 52.1813862660549))', 4326);  
set @g =  @g.ReorientObject()
select @g, @g.STArea()
```

outputs

```
2381.30781687796
```